# INNER JOIN with condition on a column - Efficient way

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

Service_BD:

[image]

LOB:

[image]

I have a requirement now to drop the redundant columns in LOB table like industryId etc. and use Service_BD table to fetch the LOBs for industryId and then get the details of the particular LOB using LOB table.

I am trying to get a single SQL query using Inner Joins but the results are odd.

When I run a simple SQL query like this:

```
SELECT industryId, LobId 
FROM Service_BD 
WHERE industryId = 'I01' 
GROUP BY lobId
```

The results are 9 rows:

[image]

Now, I would like to join rest of the LOB columns (minus the dropped ones of course) to get the LOB details out of it. So I use the below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM LOB 
INNER JOIN Service_BD ON Service_BD.lobId = LOB.lobId 
WHERE Service_BD.industryId = 'I01' 
GROUP BY Service_BD.lobID
```

[image]

I am getting the desired results but I have a doubt if this is the most efficient way or not. I doubt because, both Service_BD and LOB tables have huge amount of data, but I have a feeling that if `GROUP BY Service_BD.lobID` is performed first that would reduce the time complexity of `WHERE` condition.

Just wanted to know if this is the right way to write the query or are there any better ways to do the same.

Comment: Your query is correct. One thing you could do to speed it up slightly is to move the `WHERE` condtion in the `JOIN` clause, like `INNER JOIN Service_DB ON ServiceDB.lobID = LOB.lobID AND Service_DB.IndustryId='I01'`. But this might depend on the RDBMS you're using, which I don't see it metioned anywhere.

Comment: Since the query contains columns in the SELECT clause that are not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause, I guess it's MySQL - AFAIK no other RDBMS also has this strange "feature".

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: if `lobID` is the primary key (or a unique key), it is actually valid (standard) SQL and would work on Postgres as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27561914/330315

Comment: Yes it is MySQL and lobId is a primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . `lobID` is *not*  a primary key because it has duplicate values.  Your point is taken in general though.  It not only works in Postgres but it is acceptable by the standard in that case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Not to be pedantic, but the second image for `LOB` has `lobid` as the second column, and that column has duplicates.  The first image for `Service_BD` has `lobid` as the last column, and it also has duplicates.  I admit these images are difficult to read, but `lobid` can't be a primary key in either table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which DB engine you are using so I guess you are using MySQL. [In most cases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213250%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) the `GROUP BY` will be done only on the rows meeting the `WHERE` condition. So the `GROUP BY` is performed only on the fetched result of both the `INNER JOIN` and the `WHERE` clause.

I don't think

```
SELECT * 
FROM LOB INNER 
JOIN Service_BD ON Service_BD.lobId = LOB.lobId 
WHERE Service_BD.industryId = 'I01' 
GROUP BY Service_BD.lobID
```

improves the performance of your query but it certainly eliminates duplicate `lobID` from your result. Also, I don't see any other better way to eliminate duplicates except introducing the `HAVING` clause but I don't think it's going to improve the performance of your query.