# SQL: group by table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Suppose we use PostgreSQL and have 2 tables, `department` and `employee`, the latter belonging and having a FK into the former.

We now want to do an aggregate select, where we want to put all the information from `department` and then some aggregate values from `employee`:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, d.budget, count(*), avg(e.salary), max(e.age), sum(e.children)
FROM department d LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.dept = d.id
GROUP BY d.id, d.name, d.budget
```

I don't like that I need to specify all the columns from `department` in the `GROUP BY` - is there a way to "group by the whole table"?

And a bit more philosophical question, suppose I do `GROUP BY d.id`. Assuming `d.id` is the primary key of `department`, why do I need to group by all the other columns as well?

Comment: id `id` is the primary key of the `department` table, a simple `group by d.id` should be enough: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27561914/330315

Comment: Indeed, let me mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Why would he need group by then if its primary key?

Comment: As I said in the question text, I want to retrieve full `department` info alongside with some aggregated `employee` data.

Comment: @vektor This looks like a slightly different question then the one in stackoverflow.com/q/27561914/330315 because it sounds as if the question is about why there is no group by department. We know that some database vendors provide group by primary_id, but what about  group by department where the  user does not have to specify the primary key

Answer (score 0):

If `employee` is pre aggregated then there is no need to list the `select` columns

```
select *
from
    department d
    left join (
        select
            dept as id,
            count(*) as count_employee,
            avg(salary) as avg_salary,
            max(age) as max_age,
            sum(children) as sum_children
        from employee
        group by dept
    ) e using (id)
```

The `using` clause avoids the joined on column duplicity.